# Android SQLite cursor/adapter cannot get data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I have a gridview class here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ID: "
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridCode"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridDay"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridStart"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridDuration"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridType"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/gridRoom"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridTable"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="15dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:numColumns="7"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and a database helper:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //database information
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME    = "timetable.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME       = "timetable_data";

    //the data each column will store
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "CODE";
    public static final String COL_3 = "DAY";
    public static final String COL_4 = "START";
    public static final String COL_5 = "DURATION";
    public static final String COL_6 = "TYPE";
    public static final String COL_7 = "ROOM";


    //construct the database
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,CODE TEXT,DAY TEXT,START TEXT,DURATION TEXT,TYPE TEXT,ROOM TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String code, String day, String start, String duration, String type, String room)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,code);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,day);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,start);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,duration);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,type);
        contentValues.put(COL_7, room);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return data;
    }

    public Integer deleteEntry(String id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"ID = ?", new String [] {id});
    }
}
```

I'm trying to populate this gridview with data stored in the database, everything compiles fine, but in the app i get an error saying that data from Col-1 (the id column) cannot be retrieved.

this is the gridviewactivity.java class mentioned in the above code:

```
public class GridViewActivity extends MainActivity
{
    private GridView gridTable;
    private ArrayList<String> moduleList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Cursor data;

    DatabaseHelper timetableDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     setContentView(R.layout.gridview);

        //GridView
        gridTable=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridTable);

        String id, code, day, time, duration, type, room;

        id = "";        code = "";      day = "";       time = "";
        duration = "";  type = "";      room = "";

        timetableDB = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());//getting the context object
        timetableDB.getAllData();

        try
        {
            //for holding retrieve data from query and store in the form of rows
            Cursor data=timetableDB.getAllData();
            moduleList  =   new ArrayList<>();

            //Move the cursor to the first row.
            if(data.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    id          =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("id"));
                    code        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("code"));
                    day         =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("day"));
                    time        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("time"));
                    duration    =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("duration"));
                    type        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("type"));
                    room        =   data.getString(data.getColumnIndex    ("room"));

                    //add in to array list
                    moduleList  .   add(id);
                    moduleList  .   add(code);
                    moduleList  .   add(day);
                    moduleList  .   add(time);
                    moduleList  .   add(duration);
                    moduleList  .   add(type);
                    moduleList  .   add(room);
                }
                while(data.moveToNext());//Move the cursor to the next row.
                adapter     =   new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,moduleList);
                gridTable.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No data found "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        timetableDB.close();
    }
}
```

am i using the cursor correctly in this class?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> am i using the cursor correctly in this class?

Yes, but problem is creating `ArrayAdapter` in wrong place.

Create object of `ArrayAdapter` after adding all items in `moduleList` ArrayList from Cursor.like:

```
do{
  // add items in moduleList
}
while(data.moveToNext());//Move the cursor to the next row.

// create ArrayAdapter object here:
adapter     =   new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,moduleList);
// call setAdapter
gridTable.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated the OP with your code, is that more like it?

Answer (score 0):

The "id" column doesn't exist.
When you're creating the database you're using "ID" as the column name and not "id" so when you're calling data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("id")); it won't be able to find the column.

Comment: Should I be using getInt() instead?

Comment: You should use the same column name in both cases.

Comment: I have replaced all instances of "id" with "ID", however the same error still occurs. Should I try the same but with "_ID"?

Comment: There is no need to use "_ID" unless you've used that as the column name when you've created the table. From the code posted in your question it would seem that the column name you used is "ID" and thus you should use the same name when you're querying for data.

What is the exact error you're getting ?

Comment: ID is indeed the name, I viewed the table with SQLitebrowser just to make sure, but the full error is: "No data found Couldnt read row 0 col -1 from cursor window. Make sure the cursor is initialised correctly before accessing data from it"

Comment: The error message is telling you what the problem is: "couldn't read row 0 from column -1". It's looking for a column with an index of -1. That index does not exist. Column indexes are 0 based(start at 0). I suggest you separate data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("id") in 2 separate method calls in order to make the error more clear. Have a look at the documentation for Cursor: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)).